# In C, does an array 'access' without storing in a variable actually read from memory?

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to measure the time it takes for memory accesses, and we're to run loop and access elements from a char array. Here is my code:

```
int i;
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start);
for(i = 0; i < size; i+=stride)
{
    array[i];
}
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &stop);
```

My question is: does the statement 'array[i]' without storing its value in a variable, e.g. char x = array[i], still make the array access to memory?

Comment: Depends on the compiler implementation. Try disassembling the result your compiler gives you. Any reasonable optimising compiler should figure out that the statement `array[i]` has no side-effects, so can be dropped safely.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by "memory access".

The language specification does not have a concept of "memory access". The closest it has to offer is the concept of *lvalue conversion* described 6.3.2.1 of C11. The process of converting an lvalue to a non-lvalue is essentially the language-level idea of reading data from storage into some intermediate ethereal "holding area" for further processing. The language specification says that *lvalue conversion* is applied always, "except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator, the unary & operator, the ++ operator, the -- operator, or the left operand of the . operator or an assignment operator". That does not exclude your example, meaning that lvalue conversion is applied to the result of `array[i]`, i.e. purely conceptually the data is read from memory.

Of course, in real life no self-respecting compiler will waste its efforts on evaluating the value of `array[i]` only to discard it immediately afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

The most probable answer would be no. Compiler should eliminate such code, as all modern compilers perform optimisations.

Also, even in case compiler will leave everything as is, processor will probably cache the array, so there will be no real RAM access (so you'll get wrong timings).

Answer (score 0):

I try your code:

```
#include <time.h>

struct timespec start, stop;

void main() {
    int i;
    int size = 1000;
    int stride = 1;
    char array[size];

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start);
    for(i = 0; i < size; i+=stride) { array[i]; }
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &stop);
}
```

Then compile and dissamble it using gcc and objdump:

```
...
4005e1: eb 06                   jmp    4005e9 <main+0x8c>
4005e3: 8b 45 dc                mov    -0x24(%rbp),%eax
4005e6: 01 45 d4                add    %eax,-0x2c(%rbp)
4005e9: 8b 45 d4                mov    -0x2c(%rbp),%eax
4005ec: 3b 45 d8                cmp    -0x28(%rbp),%eax
4005ef: 7c f2                   jl     4005e3 <main+0x86>
...
```

You can see and there are no array[i]. It only using i, size, and stride.

It is not accesed.

Just like in the command any decent compiler will remove it.

Answer (score 0):

As the others have indicated -- almost certainly not.

You can, however, force the compiler to access memory through the use of the volatile keyword.

```
uint8_t volatile dest;
uint8_t volatile * p = malloc(size);
int i;
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start);
for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    dest = p[i];
}
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &stop);
```

(Note that I haven't run that code, and you'll need to adjust the C types to match the stride value that I removed)

That will get you past the compiler (but verify by looking at the disassembly anyway).

As Max pointed out, at that point, your CPU's memory architecture and memory manager hardware configuration will then determine whether fetches to physical RAM actually occur or not (and in what order).  There's not enough information in the question here to effectively address (pun intended, sorry...) that issue.

Comment: And at this point, it's unclear whether the timing one would measure has much correlation to what the OP hopes to measure.